# index rebalancing question

Tags: stocks, etf, mutual-funds, index-fund, rebalancing

When the S&P 500 adds or removes companies, my intuition is that the companies added have a higher market cap than the companies removed. To what extent does this difference drive the growth of the S&P 500? Also, wouldn't this cause index funds to lag behind the actual index because swapping a low market cap company for a high market cap company increases the market cap of the index, but the index fund wouldn't be able to capture that gain through market trades?

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret your question to be honest. Do you suggest / believe that adding companies changes the value of the index immediately or over the long run because these companies are more profitable?

Comment: I'm saying it changes the value immediately because the market cap of the company added is higher than the market company dropped.  The value of the index is the sum of the market caps of the companies on the index.  Another example would be if, say, two top 500 companies merge.  Then the s&p would get a new 500th company effectively for free.  But how would an index fund acquire that company for free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index level is unaffected by index rebalancings. It is true that prices and outstanding shares change during rebalancing, but the divisor will change to account for this.

(Divisor) after rebalancing =
Index market value after rebalancing/ Index value before rebalancing

Every index will show the calculations online, see for example [this link](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/methodologies/methodology-index-math.pdf) for the S&P500.

Answer (score 1):

See past answers. The S&P is explicitly intended to track the behavior of the top 500 companies at any given time. Which companies do or don't make the cut can be affected by a smaller company getting larger and pushing another out, or a big company getting smaller and pulling a replacement in. The effect on the index follows directly from that change, and obviously can be in either direction.

However, my impression is that movement of the market as a whole plays a much greater part in the results; I wouldn't waste time trying to micro-analyze it.